# Delete a duplicated line (only if it's the next one!)

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

Is it possible to use a function in Excel 2003 to delete an entire row if it's the same as the previous one? For example:

1. apple
2. apple
3. plum
4. vinegar
5. apple
6. banana
7. banana
8. banana
9. apple

I want to delete #2, 7# and #8, but I don't want #5 and #9 to be deleted. I want to delete a duplicated entry ONLY IF it's the next one. I hope I managed to keep it clear to you.
If there isn't a function, how can I do that in VBA? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that might fit, deleting all duplicate rows (physically, not only cell data!), so keep in mind that it can be used only if you use one-column sheets. Otherwise you will loose some other data.

```
Sub Unduplicate()
 Dim prev As String
 Dim sel As Range
 Dim i As Integer

 Set sel = Range(Selection, Selection)
 prev = sel.Offset(0).Value     ' set prev as the first value - never will be deleted
 i = 1    ' start from 2nd row
 Do While sel.Offset(i).Value <> "" And sel.Offset(i).Value <> ""
    If sel.Offset(i).Value = prev Then    ' if duplicate - delete row
        sel.Offset(i).EntireRow.Delete
    Else      ' else set new prev, and go further
        prev = sel.Offset(i).Value
        i = i + 1
    End If
 Loop
End Sub
```

After running this macro for your example, I'm getting:

[image: after-run view vba]

You can modify it, to store the values in an array, and than fill the column with remembered array instead of deleting the rows, but that should be easy now.

Answer (score 5):

If it is a one-off, you can do it without VBA fairly simple by adding a formula in the next column - let's say your column is A:

- in B2 put the following:

  ```
  =IF(A1=A2,"DELETE","")
  ```
- drag the formula down
- add an autofilter on both columns
- filter on "DELETE" in column B
- delete all visible rows
- remove column B

Comment: @molnardenes Autofill will do the job in a matter of milliseconds regardless of array size. +1 for that solution - you do not VBA here. Well, only if you wish to bring complexity and joy)

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick note...Make sure you work your way from the bottom of the range if you are deleting entire rows. You may get some unexpected results if you work your way down from the top of the range. You may also want to consider clearing the cell value and then sorting, instead of deleting. I would write up an example for you but I am short on time. If you get stuck I can write it for you later.

**Edit:**

My original answer is not necessarily true as shown in makciook's solution below. In the past I have mistakenly approached the problem this way  (DO NOT USE THIS AS A SOLUTION!!!):

```
  Sub duplicates()
  Dim c As Range, rng As Range

  Set rng = Selection ''Select the entire list before running

  For Each c In rng

      If c.Value = c.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then c.EntireRow.Delete

  Next

  End Sub
```

With this script, the cell range does not reset once a row is deleted and shifted up. So running this would not catch the second duplicate of banana in your list. As an alternative I usually find the last row and work my way up to the first row to account for the rows shifting up when a deletion occurs. I am going to give myself a -1 if possible.